# How to output data in a certain form?

Tags: c#

I have a homework problem that I need help with.

[This is the assignment question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1IwP.jpg)

So I have the following code for my class:

```
    public Tests(String firstName, String lastName, int[] testScores)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.testScores = testScores;
    }

    //First Name getter and setter
    public String GetFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void SetFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    //Last Name getter and setter
    public String GetLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void SetLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    //Test Scores getter and setter
    public int[] GetTestScores()
    {
        return testScores;
    }

    public void SetTestScores(int[] testScores)
    {
        this.testScores = testScores;
    }

    //This method calculates the average of the test scores for each student.
    public double CalculateAverage(int[] testScores)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < testScores.Length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + testScores[i];
        }
        double average = sum / testScores.Length;
        return average;
    }

    //This method returns the letter grade from the test average.
    public char WhatIsGrade(double avgTestScore)
    {
        char grade;

        if (avgTestScore >= 90)
        {
            grade = 'A';
            return grade;
        }
        else if (avgTestScore >= 80 && avgTestScore < 90)
        {
            grade = 'B';
            return grade;
        }
        else if (avgTestScore >= 70 && avgTestScore < 80)
        {
            grade = 'C';
            return grade;
        }
        else if (avgTestScore >= 60 && avgTestScore < 70)
        {
            grade = 'D';
            return grade;
        }
        else
        {
            grade = 'F';
            return grade;
        }
    }

    //Updates the score of a test
    public void modifyGrade(int testNumber, int newScore)
    {
        testScores[testNumber] = newScore;
    }
```

So once I did the class, I thought it would be pretty simple with writing the driver code in the main method.

Here is what I have so far in my main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] scores = new int[5];

        Console.WriteLine("Student 1 First Name: ");
        String student1First = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Student 1 Last Name: ");
        String student1Last = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter score: ");
            scores[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        }
```

The only thing I can think of is to write this code for each student. But then I run into the problem of finding the sum for each student's scores. I also run into the problem of how to store each student's data so that I can print it out at the end in a table form. I am guessing that I have to import the class so I did so like this:

```
Tests t1 = new Tests(firstName, lastName, arrayName)
```

But I get confused as to how it will be for each one and how to actually store anything in these. Can somebody explain step by step? Also if I have done anything wrong in my class, can somebody point it out?

Comment: You can check each step under debugger. Also `how it will be for each one and how to actually store anything in these` is not clear for me what is the question here?

Comment: Basically, I need to ask the user for each student's first name, last name, and test scores. Then I need to calculate the average of the test scores for each student. And then from that average, I need to find what their letter grade would be(A, B, C, D, or F). After doing that for each student, I have to print out a table, that lists each student, their grades, and the averages. And at the bottom of the table, I have to list the class average.

Also, the user has to input all of the data for each student. I cannot hard code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright lets start with your class.  So looks like you're missing 2 things in your Tests constructor, you're gonna wanna add the logic to set the value of the average and the letter grade to the constructor.  Gonna want to make a getter and setter for each of those as well.  In the CalculateAverage() and WhatIsGrade() you dont need the arguments since you've already pass that data to the class, so you can get rid of those and change the logic to reference the data you set in your constructor. So the constructor should look something like this now:

```
public Tests(String firstName, String lastName, int[] testScores)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.testScores = testScores;
    average = CalculateAverage();
    grade = WhatIsGrade();

}
```

Now onto the main class, unless your teacher wants all the data entered manually you can just hardcode all the data. If not you can just take all the user input in a loop. And according to your assignment you need to store each Tests object into an array of objects. So hardcoded it would look something like this

```
Tests[] testArray = new Tests[]
{
    new Tests(your data here),
    new Tests(your data here),
    etc
};
```

For output you'll want to make a method that overrides the default ToString method, you can read more about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8

That'll be where you do the formatting your teacher requested, then its just as simple as running through that array of objects with a loop and calling the ToString method on each object in the array.

---

Alright so outside of the loop go ahead and make an empty array of objects.  Then within the loop you can do what you've already done in your main, just within the loop.  You'll want to store each of the user inputs into a temporary variable just like you've already got in your main then at the very end of the loop you'll just need to add each object to your array of objects. Loop should look something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < testArray.Length; i++)
{
    int[] scores = new int[5];

    Console.WriteLine("Student First Name: ");
    String studentFirst = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Student Last Name: ");
    String studentLast = Console.ReadLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < scores.Length; j++)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter score: ");
        scores[j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    }
    testArray[i] = new Tests(studentFirst, studentLast, scores);
}
```

---

So in your overridden ToString method, before the return statement you'll want to declare a temporary string variable to hold the scores the iterate through the scores array in a for loop and add each element to the string.  It'll look something like this:

```
string scores = "";
for(int i = 0; i < testScores.Length; i++)
{
    scores = scores + testScores[i] + " ";
}
return GetFirstName() + " " + GetLastName() + " " + scores + GetAverage() + " " + GetGrade();
```

Comment: So I understand what I have to do in the class now. But in the main method, my teacher said that the user has to input all of the data manually. As in, I have to ask the user "What is the first Name, last name, 5 test scores". The problem I am having is that I do not understand how to ask that in a loop and actually store it in each object that I make. Do I just loop through and put it in the array that you showed?

Comment: Alright so outside of the loop go ahead and make an empty array of objects.  Then within the loop you can do what you've already done in your main, just within the loop.  You'll want to store each of the user inputs into a temporary variable just like you've already got in your main then at the very end of the loop you'll just need to add each object to your array of objects.  I'll edit a code example into my answer above.

Comment: Thank you so much. So I got the loop done in the main method and my class is fixed. Now all I have to do print each line. So I created a for loop and went to print it:

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arrayForTests[i].GetFirstName() + "       " + arrayForTests[i].GetLastName() + "       " + arrayForTests[i].GetTestScores());
            }

I did this just to test. The 3 should be 10 in my actual program since I will have 10 students. When I go to run the program, it says System.Int32[] instead of printing each test score.

Comment: In the assignment you linked it says "You must also write a mechanism which must return all object data as a string"  So instead of calling the getters in your main, your teacher wants you to do the formatting in an overridden ToString method that I mentioned in my answer above. Then in the loop you'd just need to put arrayForTests[i].ToString().  As for it saying System.Init32[], in the overriden ToString method, you'll want to use a for loop that runs through the scores array in the Tests class and adds it to the to your string output

Comment: So I did this: 

public override String ToString()
        {
            return GetFirstName() + " " + GetLastName() + GetAverage() + GetGrade();
        }

This is not printing anything when I call it in my loop in the main method. Also, i cannot figure out how to loop through in this toString method and then add it to my string output.

Comment: If it's exactly like that it should be returning the string, you sure you put it in a Console.WriteLine() within the loop in main?  As for adding the scores I'll edit a code example into my answer above

Comment: So I found out the reason it wasn't printing to the console. I put the return statement in the tostring method but when going to actually use the method, I had to put Console.WriteLine(testArray[i].ToString)

I just forgot to put the Console.WriteLine() because I thought it would just show up on the screen since I was returning it.

I understand now. Thank you so much for your help!